# tranform second axis in ggplot to exp

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to have two y axis, where the second is just the exp transformation of the first, same height as the original.
When I try the following:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(sample.size,eff.size))+
  geom_raster(aes(fill=value),interpolate = TRUE)+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=sub_list,
                     name="Sample Size")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=eff_list,
                     name="Log Odds Ratio",
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ exp(.)))+
```

the second axis only is out of bounds, and has does not mirror the original but in exponentional

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to format the labels for the second axis you could do so by using `dup_axis()` and the `labels=` argument like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  sample.size = 1:10,
  eff.size = log(1:10)
)

ggplot(data = df, aes(sample.size, eff.size)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Log Odds Ratio",
    sec.axis = dup_axis(labels = exp)
  )
```

[image]